# XNA - Calculating relative rotation of a bone

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, rotation

I have a skinned robotic arm model for a simulation in XNA and I am successfully able to rotate individual bones of it. Now I want to get the rotation of individual bones in degrees for saving and displaying purposes.

```
               /
              /
             /
x__________y/
```

The arm is actually in 3D space. But I want to get the 2D rotation (By that I mean a bone will only rotate on one axis)

So in the above illustration, bone "x" will have a rotation of 0 relative to the ground, and bone "y" about 100 degrees relative to bone "x" rotation

How can I calculate these values?

I hope the question is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you specify those values when you rotate the individual bones?

Comment: This is what you want.  It is not a simple topic, but it is a very rewarding project:  http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_ik.htm    http://www.williamhli.com/coding/cs283/as4

Comment: @NicoSchertler Good point. I actually do add and subtract degrees when rotating. But it would be better to be able to calculate it too. Let's say for the sake of learning some math.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the awesome link. I looked into inverse kinematics when starting the project, and thought of ruling it out for sake of simplicity. There should surely be a simpler way of calculating the angle between 2 bones given their coordinates isn't it?

Comment: @Nadeeja yes, there is definitely a simpler way to do this.  I was hoping someone would provide an answer.

Comment: You know that you can calculate the angle with the dot product of the direction vectors, right?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks. That was the missing piece theory I had forgotten.

Comment: @NicoSchertler are you familiar with XNA? I'm really stuck with matrices and vectors. How can I extract the direction vectors from the transform matrice of each bone so I can apply the dot product method as you said. is transformmatrix.Translation it?

Comment: I'm not sure, how the matrices are aligned. But it is probably the third row (of the accumulated matrix), which is the transformed z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found a link so good that I decided to post it as an answer:

http://www.ryanjuckett.com/programming/animation/16-analytic-two-bone-ik-in-2d?showall=1

There is a C# sample at the bottom of the page.